# Play video on the next Activity with fullscreen button

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

Everything works fine without the Main2Activity but what I want to do is to play the video on Main2Activity when I click the fullscreen button. Everything works well on MainActivity but when I click the fullscreen button it crashes. Not sure why. I'm new to Android development, any help would be appreciated.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button buttonPlay;
    Button buttonFullScreen;
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    VideoView resultvideo;
    MediaController mediacontroller;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediacontroller = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);

        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);

        resultvideo.setMediaController(mediacontroller);

        Button click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    }

    public void dispatchTakeVideoIntent(View v) {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            Log.i("test","111111111111111" + videoUri.toString());
            resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);
            resultvideo.pause();

        }
        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        {
            buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediacontroller.show();
                    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);
                    resultvideo.start();
                    Log.i("test","111111111111111");
                }
            });
        }

        buttonFullScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFullScreen);
        {
            buttonFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Main2Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            Log.i("test", "111111111111111" + videoUri.toString());
            resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);
            resultvideo.pause();

        }
        buttonFullScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFullScreen);
        {
            buttonFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediacontroller.show();
                    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);
                    resultvideo.start();
                    Log.i("test","111111111111111");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your crash log

Comment: Post your crash log, and don't add java code as snippets!

Comment: what is written on crash log???

Answer (score 0):

resultvideo is declared in MainActivity, it is not available in Main2Activity

Comment: It still crashes.

Comment: please post your crash log here

Answer (score 0):

`mediacontroller` and `resultvideo` are declared in MainActivity where they are in `Main2Activity`? You must have them in layout for `Main2Activity` also, as you have them in `MainActivity` layout and finding them by ids in `Main2Activity` is also necessary.